# Parse: Calling created data relations in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two classes on Parse.com named Companies and Offers and the Offers class has a pointer column to Companies, so for every company there can be multiple offers. How can I create a query in android(Java) that will display all offers for a company based on the relationship?

Edit: Other details I didn't add:-
There's actually four classes and they are: Offers, Companies, Venues and Cities.
I need to get and display "offers" from all "venues" of a "company" in a "city" or cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Offers");
query.whereEqualTo("yourCompanyPointerColumnName", yourCompanyParseObject);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> offersList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Offers retrieved successfully
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

`yourCompanyPointerColumnName` is the name of the column in your `Offers` class which is a pointer to `Companies` class.

`yourCompanyParseObject` is the `Company` object for which you want to retrieve `Offers` for.

**UPDATE:**

To get all `Offers` for all the `Companies`, just remove the `whereEqualTo` and this time use the `include()`:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Offers");
query.include("yourCompanyPointerColumnName");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> offersList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // All Offers retrieved successfully
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I Want to get all offers for all the companies and match them in a sort of array, how do I go about that using the above example?. Thanks in advance KriZ

Comment: See update above. You'll have to use `include()` to get the associated `Company` data since you'll need that to filter out the `Offers` per company later. You can use the `NSPredicate` for that.

Comment: Thanks @kRiZ, I also updated my question above, please take a look at it. Achieving that will get me moving with my current project.

Comment: How are those classes related to each other?

Comment: They all have a relation column in offers, is that the right way to do things?  @kRiZ

Comment: Can't say if that is right/wrong since I don't know what business logic you are trying to model there. But again, it'll be similar to above: to include a pointer data, use  `query.include("...");` and to add a constraint, use `query.whereEqualTo("...", ...);`

Comment: Is there anyway to move this conversation elsewhere so that I can explain what I really want to achieve?, I do not have enough reputation to chat @kRiZ

Comment: What would you like to use?

Comment: I'll like to use skype @kRiZ